# "Recently Undeleted" posts in the mod tools are almost unreadable

Tags: bug, design

I was browsing through the [mod tools](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tools) (only visible to users with >2k rep, sorry) and saw this:

[image: screenshot]

The "Recently Deleted" posts show up just fine, but the "Recently Undeleted" ones are so pale as to be almost invisible against a white background. I literally didn't see them at first.

Is this a design bug? Something that can be fixed? I haven't noticed it on any other sites.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the case for me as well (Opera 46.0.2597.26, Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: Same on Chrome (59.0.3071.109), Windows 10.

Comment: This is also the case on [SFF](https://imgur.com/a/PCdUo), which makes me think it's by design (though I can't see the necessity of such design).

Comment: @Gallifreyan Huh. In that case, I wonder if it's a recent design change. I don't remember having any readability issues with the 10k tools on SFF or Puzzling before.

Comment: Are those "Recently Deleted" posts instances of votes to delete by 2k users, or moderator deletes?  If you aren't a moderator, my recollection is that delete/undelete actions taken by moderators will be in gray. (but I don't have a non-mod 10k account to test with)

Comment: @Nathaniel Both. Whether a post is (un)deleted by community vote or by a modhammer, it'll show up in that section of the 2k/10k tools.

Comment: I mean, my recollection is that a darker blue link will appear if it's a community vote, but a modhammered post will be linked in gray (since the community can't reverse in that case).

Comment: @Nathaniel What about posts deleted by the Community bot? (which I think covers all the recently deleted questions on Lit) It has a diamond, but non-mods can vote to undelete its deletions.

Comment: Community bot would also be in blue.  Only modhammered stuff would be in gray.

Comment: I checked on SFF, and a hovertext appears on the greyed posts, saying I can't vote to delete/undelete. It seems to be by design, but I agree it could be made more readable.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Well, that's odd, because I'm not getting that hovertext for [this answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/what-is-the-neon-god-in-simon-and-garfunkels-lyrics/2851#2851) which was deleted by a moderator. Maybe it only goes for questions? Anyway, you're right - all the greyed-out ones have that hovertext. Want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Relevant dupe-ish request on main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96438/348200

Answer (score 2):

Those items appear to be dimmed when deleted single-handedly, or migrated, by a moderator. Indeed, those two posts: [Should "New Spring" be read before the rest of books in the Wheel of Time series?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1820/11) and [Please help identify a fanfic-y apocryphal story based on Noon Universe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2323/11) appear greyed because they were undeleted by one user and a moderator. If one was to hover over them, a text appears saying "you can't vote to delete/undelete this post".

There is a feature request on the main meta - [Dimmed things in mod tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96438/348200) - which asks for the same UI improvement as this one.

Comment: Wait, we can't vote to delete a post which has been undeleted by a mod? I thought we could. I know for sure that the OP can delete a mod-undeleted post.

Comment: The sample space is small here, and I can't vote either way on SFF yet.

Comment: That's true. I assumed, since the delete button disappeared from mod-undeleted questions, it would disappear from mod-deleted tools if I was unable to vote anyway.